# Git: restore diverged repository after failed rebase

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I ran a `git pull --rebase`, and aborted this after fixing several merge-conflicts using `git rebase --abort`.

Before the attempted rebase, `git status` told me: "Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 20 commits."
Now I get: "Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged, and have 15 and 5 different commit(s) each, respectively."

I have already done a reset to the latest commit (`git reset --hard c15...e30`), but the status message is still the same.

How do I revert my repository to the state is was before I started the mess? And what is the difference between the current state and the previous?

Thanks.

Comment: What does git status report as your current branch (the first line of the output)? Also, for reference, what are the relevant commit hashes for origin/master, yourbranch and where you are now (top of "git log")? Use gitk --all to give you a better picture if you need one.

Answer (score 1):

The `git rebase --abort` should have taken you back to your original HEAD.  I'm not sure what you meant by "fixing several merge-conflicts using ... abort".  Did you mean `--continue`?

Anyway, the thing to do now is consult the reflog.  The reflog is a local, temporal log of where all of your references have been.  If you look at `.git/logs/HEAD` you can see where HEAD (the working set) has been.  Under `.git/logs/refs/...` you can see where all of your branches (local and remote) have been.  Each line in the log reflects some action.  The starting SHA, ending, user, time, and a string describing what action caused the change.  You can find the one you want and `reset` back to it.